# window.name is not persistent in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm seeing a strange behavior in Google Chrome, using the `window.name` property.

For example:

1. open a tab and go to http://google.com .
2. Open up console, and type `window.name="hello"`.
3. Now in the *same* tab, go to http://chase.com.
4. In the console, type `window.name`.

I expect to see `"hello"` returned, but instead I see `""`.

Is this a known issue for Google Chrome? It works for me in FireFox.

Anyone have any insight to this behavior?

Thanks!

---

Update:

If, instead of typing in a new URL, I type `window.location="http://chase.com"`, then the `window.name` persists!

Comment: Use the HTML5 `localStorage` object to store persistent data.

Answer (score 2):

`window` is a global object for each document, not for the browser window. In a page with iframes you will have one `window` for each iframe for example. Each time a document is loaded, a new global object is created and populated for the context. When the document is unloaded, the global object along with all its data is destroyed.

Comment: @iight Now, *that* is the real question :D

Comment: Yea hahha... so now i just figured out that it's probably due to the fact that I'm typing in a new URL. If, instead, I type `window.location="http://chase.com"` then the `window.name` persists...

Comment: Whatt??? What console are you using...it might be that the console has it's own `window` and you're setting properties on that.

Comment: I tested and I have to agree. The `name` property of the `window` is persisted even in a cross-domain scenario. It doesn't work with functions or other "random" properties. Nice finding :)

Comment: @Tihauan yea window.name seems to work cross domain (if redirecting naturally and not via new $_GET request or typing in URL manually). Also found out that chrome and firefox treat typing urls into the browser differently. Firefox keeps window.name, chrome views it as a new window. good to know!

Answer (score -2):

Chrome might start a new process depending on the site.

I would call what Chrome does perfectly acceptable.

You really shouldn't be dependent on any global variable to be persistent. I would consider using session or local storage.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this has *nothing* to do with processes. The `window` context is very much tied to the page/document, independent of thread/process implementation - otherwise exploits of "persistent data" could be used. The real question, is what is *really* happening in FF?